# Android How to generate java code from the json url

Tags: android, json

i know something like json.exe are there to generate java code for json format,
please any one give me that link to generate java code from the url

like , i pass the url : any xyz url

and it give me generator code like :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
if (obj.getString("status").equals("success")) {

    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("response");
    UserNotificationTime jour;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

        obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        Appconstants.data=obj.getString("data");
    }
}
```

Comment: there are any other soluion for generate java code from the url ???

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is to you Argo: http://argo.sourceforge.net/

It is a good tool and I use it quite often